# Multiple php versions simultaneously on Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache-2.2, ubuntu, fastcgi, suexec

I want to be able to run multiple php versions on my development box running Ubuntu 12.04. What I want to accomplish is that when I use localhost as a domain a default is used (let's say php 5.3.17). When I use 547.localhost as domain php 5.4.7 is used. I've seen some tutorials to get this working using fastcgi but until now I haven't been able to get it to work.
I've looked at these tutorials:

1. http://dbforch.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/apache2-fastcgi-multiple-php-versions-ubuntulucid-10-04/
2. http://www.metod.si/multiple-php-versions-with-apache-2-fastcgi-phpfarm-on-ubuntu/

For as far as I can see I have done everything that is needed. The problem is that php simply doesn't run. When I go to `http://localhost/somephpfile.php` it just outputs the source of the php file. The same for `http://547.localhost/somephpfile.php`.

I'll break down what steps I took in the hope that someone is able to spot what I missed.

1. First I installed a default lamp stack using `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin`. After this, I had a working development server running the repository version of php.
2. Then I used phpfarm to create two php installs, one for 5.3.17 and one for 5.4.7. The localion of phpfarm is  `/etc/php/phpfarm`, so the executables are in `/etc/php/phpfarm/inst/php-{version}/bin`
3. Then I enable suaxec and fastcgi for apache and disable mod_php with `sudo a2enmod fastcgi actions suexec && sudo a2dismod php5`
4. Next, I edited `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf` to read:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>   
       FastCgiIpcDir /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi  
       FastCgiWrapper /usr/lib/apache2/suexec   FastCgiConfig -idle-timeout
       110 -killInterval 120 -pass-header HTTP_AUTHORIZATION -autoUpdate  
       ScriptAlias /php-fcgi/ /var/www/cgi-bin/ 
   </IfModule>
   ```
5. Then in `/var/www/` I created a folder cgi-bin and in this folder two files, for each of the two php versions as follows (I show only the one for 5.3.17 `/var/www/php5317.fcgi`):

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   # you can change the PHP version here.
   version="5.3.17"
   # php.ini file location, */php-5.2.13/lib equals */php-5.2.13/lib/php.ini.
   PHPRC=/etc/php/phpfarm/inst/php-${version}/lib/php.ini
   export PHPRC

   PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=3
   export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN

   PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
   export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS

   # which php-cgi binary to execute
   exec /etc/php/phpfarm/inst/php-${version}/bin/php-cgi
   ```
6. The last step was to create virtual hosts. In the end I have three files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`: 000-default, php5.3.17 and php5.4.7 With the following contents:

   default:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www
     <Directory "/var/www">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
       AddHandler php-cgi .php
       Action php-cgi /php-fcgi/php5317.fcgi
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   php5.3.17:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName 5317.localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www
     <Directory "/var/www">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
       AddHandler php-cgi .php
       Action php-cgi /php-fcgi/php5317.fcgi
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   php5.4.7:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName 547.localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www
     <Directory "/var/www">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
       AddHandler php-cgi .php
       Action php-cgi /php-fcgi/php547.fcgi
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
7. Finally I changed /etc/hosts to read

   ```
   127.0.0.1   localhost
   127.0.0.1   547.localhost
   127.0.0.1   5317.localhost

   # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
   ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
   fe00::0 ip6-localnet
   ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
   ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
   ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
   ```

Now I would expect things to work, but sadly they don't. Instead of that, a php file runs through php it just outputs the raw file.

There must be something I missed here, but I have gone through the process many times and I can't figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: 1 thing I encountered was that if I named the cgi files like you did it did not work. Try renaming `/var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi-5.4.7` to `/var/www/cgi-bin/php54.fcgi` for example or just `/var/www/cgi-bin/php.fcgi`. Can u check if that helps? Just for the 5.4.7 version.

Comment: I have checked and unfortunately this doesn't help. I have changed the virtualhost to reflect this change as well so the the action line read `Action php-cgi /php-fcgi/php547.fcgi`

Comment: I've updated the post to reflect these changes since I think is good to have it like that anyway

Comment: Hmm, I'll check for other posibilities then. :)

Comment: I was wondering, probably I don't need the suexec stuff since I don't need different users for each php version right?

Comment: You wouldn't believe how stupid I feel at this point. It works, and it would't because I used <? instead of <?php and I did not set short open tag on. Anyway, it works as described. Thank you all for thinking along!

Comment: Ha! Nice catch! Good to know the tutorial still works. ;)

Comment: There is however one more strange thing. localhost/phpmyadmin doesn't go to phpmyadmin anymore. Instead it just outputs the raw index.php file. I think I remember reading somewhere that suexec doesn't allow for anything to be outside the /var/www folder (or actually the root set for suexec and it doesn't allow symlinks. Php is of course outside this folder since it is an install from the ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Phpmyadmin is "fixed" when I add `AddHandler php-cgi .php` and `Action php-cgi /php-fcgi/php5317.fcgi` to its apache.conf. The things is now that I cannot login to mysql from phpmyadmin. I don't know whether this has anything to do with this setup, but it did work before I started with the whole fastcgi part

Comment: Actually, mysql has stopped working completely, it fails with this error `[2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your virtualhosts you added a handler, but you didn't set the handler which is why it isn't processed.  Add:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler php-cgi
</FilesMatch>
```

before `</Directory>` in each virtual hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I liked this short step-by-step overview by [SeeDoubleYou](https://serverfault.com/users/138416/seedoubleyou) and wanted to try it myself. What was missing was

- `sudo chmod +x /var/www/cgi-bin/*`

  - Since this wasn't executed, apache wasn't able to execute the cgi scripts
  - This is needed for the line `Action php-cgi /php-fcgi/php<version>.fcgi`  in the `vhost.conf` file
- `sudo apt-get install apache2-suexec-pristine libapache2-mod-fastcgi`

  - suexec executable and fastcgi module were missing, they had to be installed first
  - The suexec executable is needed for the line `FastCgiWrapper /usr/lib/apache2/suexec` in the `fastcgi.conf` file
- I also had to remove the line `FastCgiIpcDir /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi`

  - otherwise I got the error message `FastCgiIpcDir /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi: already defined as "/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi"`

For anyone trying to set php_admin_value and php_value via .htaccess or vhosts files: This isn't possible with FCGI. Instead you can use [.user.ini files](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) to set directory specific php.ini configurations.