# How to have multiple PHP on Webmin/Virtualmin

Tags: php5

I've scoured the internet for 4 hours now trying to find how to get newer PHP Versions on Webmin. No luck!

Ideally, how do you get PHP 5.5 on Webmin/Virtualmin? If this is not available yet the latest possible version

This is for ubuntu server. (They have a tutorial for cent-os but not .deb based)

Comment: Have you tried something like this? http://gregrickaby.com/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I was under the impression this was not recommended due to:
"One of the main advantages of using the installer over setting up Virtualmin manually is the APT or YUM repository that it sets up on your system. This includes Debian or RPM packages for Webmin, Usermin and the Virtualmin modules, plus modified versions of dependent programs like Apache and PHP."
I just ran the virtualmin install script from a fresh installation. Everything seems to work perfectly except PHP is old.

Comment: I'm not sure, I guess you'll have to look into it further. What does webmin say about upgrading PHP?

Comment: They don't seem to say anything except to do with Cent-OS and yum files which I can't use on ubuntu server

Answer (score 1):

It's not just about Webmin, it's about the underlying system. You can't have multiple versions of PHP at the same time in one action, especially with modules — it's not just about how to run `apt-get install`.

PHP can be used with apache **as a module**, or **with a CGI interface**. You can't have two PHP modules at the same time; you can have two php-cgi binaries, but they must have different names/locations, different locations for PHP modules, different locations for includes, etc. You have to build them manually and satisfy all the dependencies and structure. It's not that easy and It's not going to be easy to manage with virtualmin — you need to specify the PHP version for every virtualhost manually in the Apache configuration file, as SeeDeoubleYou did here: [Multiple php versions simultaneously on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/431875/multiple-php-versions-simultaneously-on-ubuntu).

You can easily run only one version of PHP with Webmin/Virtualmin, but not multiple.

Comment: What if I just want one version, the latest possible?
Could I break webmin/virtualmin if I somehow override the supplied version?

Comment: Yes, it's possible and there are changes that shouldn't affect webmin. It isn't officially supported by Canonical, but there are community repositories with PHP 5.5 packages: https://launchpad.net/~zanfur/+archive/php5.5‎ and
https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5‎

Answer (score 1):

Virtualmin has a guide on this exact issue https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/multiplephp